# How do we change the viewcontrollers of an active tabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In our app delegate we set a tab bar controller to the root view. This tab bar, on initialization, fills itself with a bunch of tabs by using setViewControllers, but none of the tabs show up and when logged, indeed [viewControllers count] returned 0. Is there someway to force the tabbarcontroller to change its viewcontrollers?

EDIT: added code

In tab bar controller m file:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        FooViewController *fooViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *fooNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fooViewController];

        BarViewController *barViewController = [[BarViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *barNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:barViewController];
        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers: @[fooNavigationController, barNavigationController] animated: NO];
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",[self.tabBarController.viewControllers count]);
    return self;
}
```

App delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    CustomTabBarController *tabController = [[CustomTabBarController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Added some code in edit.

Comment: Inside your init method, is self.tabBarController nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **set the root view controllers** of the tab bar controller.

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

> **`viewControllers`**
>
> The array of custom view controllers to display in the
>   tab bar interface. The order of the view controllers in this array
>   corresponds to the display order in the tab bar, with the controller
>   at index 0 representing the left-most tab, the controller at index 1
>   the next tab to the right, and so on.

When you assign a new set of view controllers at runtime, the tab bar controller removes all of the old view controllers before installing the new ones.

Comment: My bad, I accidentally deleted that line when I was copying over to stackexchange, but we do have that already.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Since our class inherits from UITabBarController we simply call self setViewControllers rather than self.tabBarController setViewControllers.